# ESlint in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eslint

I have been given a web project at work that has a .eslintrc file in it and was told to use it.

I gather that this enforces code styles and sounds like a good idea, but I have never done this before.

I just switched to Eclipse Neon.  But I can find no tutorials on how to use it. I did find something that says eslint is now the default linter for Eclipse but that was for Orion.  Can someone tell me how to use my .eslintrc file for all my .js files in Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-ESLint), you have to install [Tern](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java) into your Eclipse, then configure it to use the ESLint linter. It's not clear (to me) whether or not the plugin will use your `.eslintrc` for configuration; it talks about an ESLint JSON configuration file instead.

Comment: It does expect an eslint.json file,  but you can change that in the .tern-project file.  Restarted Eclipse, and all is well.

Comment: Hi @mmaceachran, I'm doing the same thing. In my case our project has .eslintignore file as well. Do u have such ignore list file? If positive, how did u manged to configure it on eclipse using Tern. Another question is what if we have more than one configuration file in our project. Lets say in sub folders we have some configs which are extending the main config file in the root?

Comment: @Vahid,  I'm sorry I can't help.  I still had so many other problems I stopped trying to get this to work.  We have our application broken in to a ton of sub-projects, one of which is just the front end of CSS, JS, and the like....  For that I use the IDE Atom, and i just use that for the front end.  The Eclipse plug-in has alot of problems.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Neon myself, and this is how you configure ESLint:

1. Create an ESLint JSON configuration file by following [these instructions](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html).
2. Go to Project / Properties / JavaScript / Tern / Validation / ESLint and check "Use config files":

   [image]
3. Enter the path to your `eslint.json` file (or whatever you named the file you created from step 1) and press OK.

If you want to disable ESLint (or any other module), go to Project / Properties / JavaScript / Tern / Modules and uncheck it.

Comment: i have enabled eslint validation like this but nothing happens in my tern project...