# Install ES7-capable linter in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eslint, lint, ecmascript-2016

Linux Mint OS, Eclipse "2019-06".

New to this idea that a linter is needed for JS.

Found out yesterday about JSLint... then JSHint.

JSHint is already there under Windows --> Prefs. But when I try to use it in a JS project it doesn't seem to cope with ES7 (or higher...): I tried setting globally as Windows --> Prefs --> JSHint --> Configuration, like so:

```
{
  "esversion": 9,
  "browser" : true
}
```

(NB I also tried with esversion 7, and also with these numbers in quotes, just in case).

Whatever I do I get errors with code like this (inside an `async` function I hasten to add):

```
const response = await fetch( filename, {
    method: 'HEAD',
    cache: 'no-cache'
});
```

... gives "Missing semicolon" and "await is not defined".

It also appears that this JSLint thing (or something else) is preventing proper autoformatting of JS files with ES7 code.

Anyway I then did a bit of searching for a linter capable of ES7 and which works in Eclipse.  I heard about ESLint, followed [these instructions](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started), and installed in the project directory: .eslintrc, package.json, node_modules, etc.

And then found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152256/eslint-in-eclipse) from 3 years ago. The trouble is that (see answers there) [Tern](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java) is now said to be "OUTDATED, it's recommended to use Eclipse Wild Web Developer instead". So I installed that.

But I can't now see what to do: Windows --> Prefs --> Javascript: there's no "Tern" subheading there... and no "Wild Web Developer" anywhere I can see.

Any possible way of installing an ES7 linter in Eclipse would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

About Eclipse Wild Web Developer, there is a work in progress about supporting eslint. When [this PR](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/pull/307) will be merged and a new release done, you will able to use eslint with Eclipse Wild Web Developer.

If you miss some features in Eclipse Wild Web Developer, feel free to create new issues here: https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues